# Create local temporary table (or view) with multiple values entered manually

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create a local temporary table or a view and enter multiple values?

I need this table to use as a filter for other tables, selecting only the products in this list. I cannot do it directly with a where because I need to use this filter multiple times. Therefore I wanted to create this table and join it so that the input needs to be entered only once.
Also, I cannot create normal tables because I don't have this kind of rights. only views or local temporary tables work for me.

This works, but I can enter only 1 product code:

```
CREATE local TEMPORARY TABLE user_input ON COMMIT preserve rows AS 
(
SELECT
'ABC' AS product  -- enter PRODUCT CODE here
)
```

I tried this to enter more than one code, but it does not work:

```
INSERT INTO user_input(product)
VALUES ('ABC','DEF','GHI)
```

Comment: your CRETE TABLE doesn't work in mysql

Comment: Please use [edit] to add the correct database you are using .... (and remove the [mysql] tag beasue your statement is not working in MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to insert *three* rows, each with one column.  That looks like:

```
INSERT INTO user_input (product)
    VALUES ('ABC'), ('DEF'), ('GHI');
```

Each set of parentheses are the values for a different row.

You can also create the table as:

```
create user_input as
    select 'ABC' as product union all
    select 'DEF' union all
    select 'GHI';
```

Or in the most recent versions of MySQL:

```
create table user_input as
    values row('ABC'), row('DEF'), row('GHI');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a view I would then create it filtering the base table

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
Select Col1, Col2
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col1 in ('A','B','C')
```

Then you can use this view to filter your queries

Comment: The original post wasn't too clear, but I don't think they're looking for a subset of an existing table. I think they mean to create the reference data table for the first time.

Comment: Since it is to filter the product from a list, I assumed he has access to a list with all the information hence the view instead of the temp table.
And by creating a view it is reusable through sessions wich a temp table can not do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UNION` to merge several selects

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testing         
 select 1 as id, 'aaa' as labels
 UNION
 select 2, 'bbb' 
 UNION
 select 3, 'ccc'  ;
```

running `SELECT * FROM testing` will output

[image]